# using SET with FROM in mysql. Attaching my query below can anyone help me with it

Tags: mysql, sql

whats wrong in below query syntax? How can we properly use SET to update column values from one q_id to another q_id.

```
UPDATE answer
SET
    expiry = newdata.expiry
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        expiry,
        q_id,
        created_at,
        seller_id
    FROM answer
    WHERE
        q_id=49
        and status='APPROVED'
        and expiry is not NULL
        and expiry < '2028-01-01 00:00:00'
        
    ) newdata
WHERE
    q_id=343
    AND created_at = newdata.created_at
    AND seller_id = newdata.seller_id
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no FROM clause in [UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) in MySQL.

```sql
UPDATE answer
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        expiry,
--        q_id,   -- excess, it is not used in outer query
        created_at,
        seller_id
    FROM answer
    WHERE
        q_id=49
        and status='APPROVED'
--        and expiry is not NULL   -- excess due to the next condition
        and expiry < '2028-01-01 00:00:00'
        
    ) newdata USING (created_at, seller_id)
SET
    answer.expiry = newdata.expiry

WHERE
    answer.q_id=343;
```

Pay attention - the subquery may return more than one row per `(created_at, seller_id)` value. In this case the value from one indefinite row from all of them will be used for updating. So GROUP BY and MIN/MAX needed in the subquery for the whole query to be deterministic.